# `which` for SunOS 5.10

Tags: solaris, which

I have (normal user) access to a SunOS 5.10 machine.

`/usr/bin/which` is broken (it blocks).

Clearly something is wrong on the system, but not having root access limits drastically what I can do. I have tried copying my `which` from Ubuntu, but that depends on features not available on SunOS 5.10.

```
$ md5sum /usr/bin/which
a39bb82e9e354c5b99e9e235a53c48d9  /usr/bin/which
$ uname -a
SunOS solaris 5.10 Generic_147147-26 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V210 Solaris
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.33(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.10)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Where can I find a `which` command that will work on this old system?

Comment: Use [`type`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-type) instead.

Comment: Although, the blocking might come from a network mount included in PATH.

Comment: `which` works, one of the mounted file systems doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

The `which` command is unlikely to be broken under Solaris 10. It is just a `csh` script<sup>1</sup>.

Should this script contents is really corrupted, you can replace it by copy pasting the following lines in it. That will restore its standard behavior.

```
#! /usr/bin/csh -f
#
# Copyright 2005 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All rights reserved.
# Use is subject to license terms.
#
# Copyright (c) 1980 Regents of the University of California.
# All rights reserved.  The Berkeley Software License Agreement
# specifies the terms and conditions for redistribution.
#
#ident  "%Z%%M% %I% %E% SMI"
#
#       which : tells you which program you get
#
# Set prompt so .cshrc will think we're interactive and set aliases.
# Save and restore path to prevent .cshrc from messing it up.
set _which_saved_path_ = ( $path )
set prompt = ""
if ( -r ~/.cshrc && -f ~/.cshrc ) source ~/.cshrc
set path = ( $_which_saved_path_ )
unset prompt _which_saved_path_
set noglob
set exit_status = 0
foreach arg ( $argv )
    set alius = `alias $arg`
    switch ( $#alius )
        case 0 :
            breaksw
        case 1 :
            set arg = $alius[1]
            breaksw
        default :
            echo ${arg}: "      " aliased to $alius
            continue
    endsw
    unset found
    if ( "$arg:h" != "$arg:t" ) then        # head != tail, don't search
        if ( -e $arg ) then         # just do simple lookup
            echo $arg
        else
            echo $arg not found
        set exit_status = 1
        endif
        continue
    else
        foreach i ( $path )
            if ( -x $i/$arg && ! -d $i/$arg ) then
                echo $i/$arg
                set found
                break
            endif
        end
    endif
    if ( ! $?found ) then
        echo no $arg in $path
    set exit_status = 1
    endif
end

exit ${exit_status}
```

However, a much more common reason for `which` to hang is an issue with one of the file systems used by the directories listed in your `PATH`.

That can be an unresponsive NFS mount or a local file system exhibiting issues.

Here is one way to start investigating. Run this command and see where it hangs:

```
csh -x /bin/which foo
```

Another reason why `which` might hang can be an issue with your `.cshrc` file as it is sourced at the beginning of the script.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>It might be argued that for the very reason it is a `csh` script, `which`is broken by design ;-)</sub>

Comment: Yup. That looks very much like the csh-script on my system that does not work.

Comment: The script works as designed. What doesn't is one of your file systems and you should fix it before the issue shows up elsewhere.

Comment: How can I fix that without root access?

Comment: Not having root privileges doesn't prevent you from diagnosing the issue and at least removing the affected directories from your PATH. Answer edited with the first steps.

Answer (score 1):

I went with:

```
#!/bin/sh

type "$@" | perl -pe 's/.* is (a tracked alias for )?//'
```

so that it can work as a drop-in replacement for `which`.

Thanks @OlafDietsche for the comment.

Comment: While that works around whatever your system's fundamental issue is, ignoring that fundamental issue won't fix things.  What *else* is wrong on that system?